# Ender 3 Pro stuck print excess

Tags: creality-ender-3

I have an Ender 3 Pro. When I print, the area that the printer goes around before printing gets stuck and I can't scrape it or use alcohol.

Both of these methods are used with a heated and cooled bed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your bed is way too close to the nozzle.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Please consider to add an answer with a little background why it is too close (this is probably the reason), the current answer doesn't include this solution!

Answer (score 2):

With PETG I use Elmer's glue sticks to form a barrier protecting my print surface.

When PETG stuck too hard to the print surface, I have to decide what to destroy; the print or the print surface.  Removing at room temperature can tear the print surface.  Heating the bed to 80 °C  or above softens the print, making it easier to remove, but distorts during removal.

If the print is already removed, you can heat the bed to make the remaining material easier to scrape off. With a glue stick, especially a washable glue stick, you can first clean off the glue stick and undercut the material on the bed.